# Changing Image position when scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to javascript and wanna create a HTML page and would like to make an image like floating on my page and it will interacting when user scrolling up and down of the website but I just couldn't figure it out. Anyone has idea how to deal with it?

```
            <script>


            $(window).scroll(function () { 
                //You've scrolled this much:
                // $('p').text("You've scrolled " + $(window).scrollTop() + " pixels");
                var doc = doc
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ImageTesting");
                //x.style.top =  "$(window).scrollTop()";
                x.css({'top': $(window).scrollTop() +'px'});

                console.log($(window).scrollTop() + "px")
                //console.log(x.style.top)
            });



            </script>
```

Comment: like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same behavior using [css's sticky property](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

```
.ImageTesting {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* safary */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple CSS properties first mentioned above The CSS Sticky property with image tag or just

```
<div class="bgFloat"></div>
<style> 
  .bgFloat {
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

It will help you to fix the image position as background. Or if you want to continue with image tag then follow the 'position: sticky; top:0' or where ever you want to place your element.